# SQL: Getting the COUNT of one table and JOIN the others

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

I have a query that looks like such:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.Value1) AS Count, B.id AS Id1, C.id AS Id2
FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON (B.Name LIKE '%UserInput1%')
LEFT JOIN Table3 C ON (C.Name LIKE '%UserInput2%')
WHERE A.Value1 LIKE 'CertainValue'
```

The query runs perfectly fine; it's just that the **COUNT** I get from `Table1` does not give me the actual count of the number of `Value1`s in `Table1`, but rather the number of `Value1`s multiplied by the number of tables that are actually joined.

Is there any way I can obtain the **COUNT** from just Table1 that fits into the criteria of `A.Value1 LIKE 'CertainValue'`, while joining the other tables?

**FYI:** I'm using MySQL!

Comment: Your query currently returns [indeterminate results](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html). What values from the other tables do you want when there are multiple matches? Is it deliberate that you have no `GROUP BY`?

Comment: You're also going to need to correlate the various tables to each other.  How do rows in `A` relate to rows in `B`?

Comment: Actually I'd like to just get individual results from each table (because the values are more or less unique), but I'd like to get the COUNT of the number of values from Table1 which corresponds to the final condition. The COUNT will be either 1 or 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing the counting after joining, so you're counting the number of A.Value1's in the resulting cross-product. If you want the count from the original table, you should use a sub-query. I don't think this will cause much of a performance problem, it should actually improve it, since it reduces the size of the resulting join.

```
SELECT ACount, B.id AS Id1, C.id AS Id2
FROM (Select COUNT(*) ACount FROM Table1 WHERE Value1 LIKE 'CertainValue') A 
LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON (B.Name LIKE '%UserInput1%')
LEFT JOIN Table3 C ON (C.Name LIKE '%UserInput2%')
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I suppose you can add `DISTINCT` to your `COUNT`.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.Value1) AS Count, B.id AS Id1, C.id AS Id2
FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON (B.Name LIKE '%UserInput1%')
LEFT JOIN Table3 C ON (C.Name LIKE '%UserInput2%')
WHERE A.Value1 LIKE 'CertainValue'
```

The whole query really isn't very pretty since you are joining tables that do not seem to have any relationship with each other.  The result set should be quite a mess.

Comment: I know it's kinda messy, but I think sub-queries will eat more into performance...? Okay I'll give it a go!

Comment: The result is right. And your solution is a bit faster compared to the subquery solution. Thanks Holger.

Answer (score 0):

The query as written will return a cartesian product because A, B and C are not joined at all.  Also, count is a keyword, best to use another identifier in the select.  Try writing the query as something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.Value1) AS MyCount, B.id AS Id1, C.id AS Id2
FROM Table1 A
LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON A.?? = B.??
LEFT JOIN Table3 C ON A.?? = C.??
WHERE A.Value1 LIKE '%CertainValue%'
AND B.Name LIKE '%UserInput1%'
AND C.Name LIKE '%UserInput1%'
GROUP BY B.id, C.id
```